# searching integers using fulltext search in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

Iam using fulltext search in  my php file using mysql.But its not giving any result for integers like "Timber Jane 10".

My requirement is to get exact search, that is, if I search a full name it should give exact matches which contains those words and in the order of best match in descending order no matter if the searched phrase is a three character word or an integer or a full name etc.

Query that I'm using is

```
select name,url from table where match (name) against ('+word*'  IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Does Full text search stops searching when there's an integers in the searched string???
Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

do this...

```
select name,url from table where name like '%Timber Jane 10%'
```

you can't really do a 'best match' thing because you have to criteria to base any relevance on.

to explain:

an exact match of 'Timber Jane 10' will always be 100% relevant
-while-
a non-exact match of 'Timber Jane' would be 66% relevant
-or-
a non-exact match of '10 Timber Jane' could be 80% relevant

either way, the query i gave will get result where the exact phrase is used